# how to use <a> tag with <content>tag

Tags: html, css

When I try to put an `<a>` tag inside the content tag, the link is not active.

This is my CSS.

```
.cta {
    padding-top: 5rem;
    padding-bottom: 5rem;
    background-color: rgba(0, 32, 96, 0.1);
}

.cta .cta-inner {
    position: relative;
    padding: 3rem;
    margin: 0.5rem;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
}

.cta .cta-inner:before {
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -0.5rem;
    bottom: -0.5rem;
    left: -0.5rem;
    right: -0.5rem;
    border: 0.25rem solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
}
```

This is my HTML

```
<div class="cta-inner text-center rounded">
  <h2 class="section-heading mb-4">
    <span class="section-heading-upper">For you</span>
    <span class="section-heading-lower">LikeLion × 7th</span>
    </h2>
     <p class="mb-0">~~~~~~~</p>
     <a href='url_adress' target='_blank'>클릭!</a>
</div>
```

Moving a tag out of the div works but does not work inside.

Also, moving them out of the div would ruin the overall design.

If I delete the `content: '';` part in css, the design disappears and a tag works, but I do not want to delete it. What should I do?

```css
    .cta {
        padding-top: 5rem;
        padding-bottom: 5rem;
        background-color: rgba(0, 32, 96, 0.1);
    }
    
    .cta .cta-inner {
        position: relative;
        padding: 3rem;
        margin: 0.5rem;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
    }
    
    .cta .cta-inner:before {
        border-radius: 0.5rem;
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: -0.5rem;
        bottom: -0.5rem;
        left: -0.5rem;
        right: -0.5rem;
        border: 0.25rem solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
    }
```

```html
<div class="cta-inner text-center rounded">
  <h2 class="section-heading mb-4">
    <span class="section-heading-upper">For you</span>
    <span class="section-heading-lower">LikeLion × 7th</span>
  </h2>
  <p class="mb-0">~~~~~~~</p>
  <a href='url_adress' target='_blank'>클릭!</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `.cta .cta-inner:before` is overlapping the entire contents. This makes your anchor not clickable. You need to find a different logic so that the anchor tag is not getting overlapped.

[image]

A possible work around would be to make anchor `position:absolute`

```
.cta .cta-inner a {
    position: absolute;
}
```

See the working code here, not sure how it affect your entire page though.

```css
.cta {
    padding-top: 5rem;
    padding-bottom: 5rem;
    background-color: rgba(0, 32, 96, 0.1);
}

.cta .cta-inner {
    position: relative;
    padding: 3rem;
    margin: 0.5rem;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
}

.cta .cta-inner:before {
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -0.5rem;
    bottom: -0.5rem;
    left: -0.5rem;
    right: -0.5rem;
    border: 0.25rem solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
}
.cta .cta-inner a {
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="cta">


  <div class="cta-inner text-center rounded">
    <h2 class="section-heading mb-4">
      <span class="section-heading-upper">For you</span>
      <span class="section-heading-lower">LikeLion × 7th</span>
    </h2>
    <p class="mb-0">~~~~~~~</p>
    <a href='url_adress' target='_blank'>클릭!</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @dj-Yang there is also another solution, please see @Johannes answer using `pointer-events`

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear what's the purpose of your `.cta .cta-inner:before` pseudo element, but it covers the parent element and thereby the link, making it inaccessible.

However, if you add `pointer-events: none;` to that CSS rule, it will allow to click "through it" and make the link inside it clickable.